# Ubuntu 20.04 GUI failed with RTX3070 Laptop and NIVIDIA 460.39 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, usb-c

I am using the 2021 ASUS TUF Gaming A15 laptop, with AMD R7 5800H CPU and GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, the system I am using is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I am trying to do some deep learning and SLAM stuffs in Ubuntu with GPU.

After I installed the NVIDIA driver (460.39), I tried graphical installation and command-line installation, both installation methods end up in a black screen when reboot with an error message saying

> usci_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)

I can get into the command-line interface with "CTRL+ATL+F2" at this point. And in the command-line interface, I can see that the driver is successfully installed, and I do have a proper output using command "*nvidia-smi*".

I did some research on why the "*usci_acpi*" error happened and it looks like it is because the USB-C port on my laptop and has some compatibility problem.

Here are some things I tried to solve this error:

1. Although NVIDIA official website says the only compatible driver for RTX 3070 laptio GPU is 460.39, I still tried my luck to install an earlier version of the NVIDIA driver 455.35. After installation, the reboot doesn't have any problem but I get the error  **No device found** when calling "*nvidia-smi*" in the terminal, which is expected.
2. I tried to update the Ubuntu kernel from 5.8 to 5.10 and the most recent 5.11. In 5.10, the error remains, I still can't get into the GUI, but the command-line interface works. In 5.11, the system goes to black screen directly after reboot, can't even try to install the NVIDIA driver.
3. I also tried the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the error remains.

Any idea how can I solve this "*usci_acpi*" problem? Any way to get around the USB-C port or I have to wait for the release of the newer nvidia driver or ubuntu kernel?